# Сортировка таблицы bash awk

Tags: bash, awk

Помогите, пожалуйста с сортировкой таблицы. Должен получиться bash скрипт с использованием awk.

1. Нужно посчитать количество одинаковых вхождений для каждого из столбцов таблицы кроме 1,2,3 столбца и дописать это количество рядом со столбцом(справа создав новый) (file_qty.csv)
2. и после этого отсортировать по одному из столбцов в порядке убывания(например по четвертому) (file_qty_sort.csv).
3. Затем из таблицы file_qty_sort.csv нужно выбрать только те строки, которые в четвертом столбце СОДЕРЖАТ текст "ata-5", без учета регистра, главное, чтобы символы совпадали, то есть "ata-5"="Ata-5"
   и получить file_qty_sort_select.csv

Не нужно все операции заталкивать в одну строку или как минимум пункт 2 и 3 должны быть реализованы отдельными командами. Исходная и другие 3 таблицы должны присутствовать в результатах.

Вот как выглядит таблица первоначально:

file.csv

```
data;data;data;data-5;data-55;data-1;data-75;data-83;data-95;data-105;data-115
data;data;data;data-5;data-57;data-5;data-77;data-83;data-97;data-107;data-117
data;data;data;data-1;data-51;data-1;data-71;data-81;data-91;data-101;data-111
data;data;data;data-5;data-56;data-6;data-76;data-83;data-96;data-106;data-116
data;data;data;data-1;data-52;data-1;data-72;data-82;data-92;data-101;data-112
data;data;data;data-3;data-53;data-1;data-73;data-83;data-93;data-103;data-113
data;data;data;data-4;data-54;data-1;data-74;data-83;data-94;data-104;data-114
data;data;data;data-6;data-58;data-4;data-78;data-83;data-98;data-108;data-118
data;data;data;data-7;data-59;data-3;data-79;data-89;data-99;data-109;data-119
```

а вот что должно получиться: (видно, что в 4-м столбце data-1 и data-5 встречаются соответственно 2 и 3 раза, что и записано в 5-м столбце, а затем 5-й столбец отсортирован)

file_qty.csv

```
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-55;1;data-1;5;data-75;1;data-83;6;data-95;1;data-105;1;data-115;1
data;data;data;data-1;2;data-51;1;data-1;5;data-71;1;data-81;1;data-91;1;data-101;2;data-111;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-56;1;data-6;1;data-76;1;data-83;6;data-96;1;data-106;1;data-116;1
data;data;data;data-1;2;data-52;1;data-1;5;data-72;1;data-82;1;data-92;1;data-101;2;data-112;1
data;data;data;data-3;1;data-53;1;data-1;5;data-73;1;data-83;6;data-93;1;data-103;1;data-113;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-57;1;data-5;1;data-77;1;data-83;6;data-97;1;data-107;1;data-117;1
data;data;data;data-4;1;data-54;1;data-1;5;data-74;1;data-83;6;data-94;1;data-104;1;data-114;1
data;data;data;data-6;1;data-58;1;data-4;1;data-78;1;data-83;6;data-98;1;data-108;1;data-118;1
data;data;data;data-7;1;data-59;1;data-3;1;data-79;1;data-89;1;data-99;1;data-109;1;data-119;1
```

file_qty_sort.csv

```
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-55;1;data-1;5;data-75;1;data-83;6;data-95;1;data-105;1;data-115;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-56;1;data-6;1;data-76;1;data-83;6;data-96;1;data-106;1;data-116;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-57;1;data-5;1;data-77;1;data-83;6;data-97;1;data-107;1;data-117;1
data;data;data;data-1;2;data-51;1;data-1;5;data-71;1;data-81;1;data-91;1;data-101;2;data-111;1
data;data;data;data-1;2;data-52;1;data-1;5;data-72;1;data-82;1;data-92;1;data-101;2;data-112;1
data;data;data;data-3;1;data-53;1;data-1;5;data-73;1;data-83;6;data-93;1;data-103;1;data-113;1
data;data;data;data-4;1;data-54;1;data-1;5;data-74;1;data-83;6;data-94;1;data-104;1;data-114;1
data;data;data;data-6;1;data-58;1;data-4;1;data-78;1;data-83;6;data-98;1;data-108;1;data-118;1
data;data;data;data-7;1;data-59;1;data-3;1;data-79;1;data-89;1;data-99;1;data-109;1;data-119;1
```

file_qty_sort_select.csv

```
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-55;1;data-1;5;data-75;1;data-83;6;data-95;1;data-105;1;data-115;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-56;1;data-6;1;data-76;1;data-83;6;data-96;1;data-106;1;data-116;1
data;data;data;data-5;3;data-57;1;data-5;1;data-77;1;data-83;6;data-97;1;data-107;1;data-117;1
```

Comment: Bash?! Если это обязательное условие, бегите оттуда! А по делу: Python `csv` или `pandas`.

Comment: Так ещё и скрипт должен быть оптимизирован под файлы с многомиллионным количеством строк

Comment: Тем более, если файлы с многомиллионным количеством строк, о каком bash вообще речь?!

Comment: @0andriy, не почему? `sed` за раза обрабатывает ровно одну строку. Так что можно хоть петабайтные таблицы на 16mb ram парсить.

Comment: @donRumata, `sed` is not `bash`. Как и `awk`, но они оба далеки от тех библиотек, которые предоставляет Python и ему подобные ЯП. Более того, Shell сам по себе — **очень** сложный ЯП, чтобы писать на нём корректно и оптимально, надо не одну собаку съесть.